# Can we find IP that logged into linux EC2 and ran particular command?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, linux-networking

We have a **linux** ec2 instance.

One of us **logged into our ec2** and ran a command,
say `python --version`.

I know the date and time they have run this command.

Now, Is there a way I can find the IP from which they logged into our ec2 and run this command?

P.S. We switch to particular user to run commands, specifically for that directory.

Comment: Without proper auditing logs, you may not even be able to tell if it was one the users of the shared (eww..) account, or if there the user was *logged in* at the time the command ran.

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: Hello @anx, We use the same user to run all commands. By this, I meant, only that user has access to run commands, in a specific directory. It's not the user we use to login. And, I do have administrator access and complete console access, if these help me find IP?

Answer (score 1):

If you configure something like [Snoopy](https://github.com/a2o/snoopy) *beforehand* then you may be able to correlate the IP with the TTY and with the command.

But note that it must be done *before* the activity and it can relatively easily be inhibited if someone is keen to hide their actions.

---

However you may still be lucky - check the output of `last` command to see who was logged in and from where. If there was only one user logged in at the time the command was run that's possibly your user/IP.

Comment: Thank you, last command helped.